# QtQml installation in Raspberry pi

Tags: qt, qml, pyqt5, raspberry-pi3, qqmlapplicationengine

I am stuck with one error while building PyQt5 for rasberry pi. I was successfully able to run the application which uses **QQmlApplicationEngine** on Windows Desktop. Now I wanted to run the same application in Raspberry pi 3. I build the PyQt5 (5.4.1v) from the source and tried running the application but I get error:

> ImportError: No Module Found "PyQt5.QtQml".

I realized that, when I build the PyQt5 from the source, I get:

> Project Error: Unknown module(s) in QT: qml

and shows me a list of modules which will be built.

Just for a reference, I am using a raspbian, and have installed the following before building PyQt5.

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install qtcreator
>
> sudo apt-get install qt5-qmake

added "export QT_SELECT = qt5" to my "~/.profile" and "~/.bashrc"

> sudo apt-get install qt5-default qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools qttools5-dev-tools build-essential libboost-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-thread-dev libssl-dev libdb++-dev libgl1-mesa-dev

How am I supposed to install QtQml in PyQt5? Please help...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyQt5 is (as you perhaps know) just a wrapper for the Qt C++ libraries. In order to use a specific module in PyQt5 the underlying C++ library needs to be installed.

The first error message shows that `PyQt5.QtQml` module is missing which respectively leads to the conclusion that the underlying Python wrapper is missing.

The second error message is probably generated on the C++ level and means that the required Qt C++ library for this module is missing.

Since you are building PyQt5 you not only need the runtime libraries but also the development packages for Qt. For QML you need the `qtdeclerative5-dev` package and the `libqt5qml5` (I think that was the name for the runtime library). These of course depend on a bunch of other packages which will automatically be installed.

PS: Don't forget the SIP library which PyQt has as a dependency no matter which Qt modules you want to use.

Comment: Yoo. Thanks... I was missing qtdeclarative5-dev and libqt5qml5. After installing, it was set work, it worked when I imported PyQt5.QtQml on python console.
Just another question, where can I find the list of dependencies required to install certain packages of PyQt5, since I am not sure when will I require another packages and will be absent. Don't want to bug anyone because of this again.

Comment: You can look at the [list of all components](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/py-modindex.html) supported by PyQt5 and from there you have to look at the [official Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io) or Google to look for clues. Dependencies (package-wise) can be retrieved by using `apt-cache depends <your-package-name>` or looking at the `Dependecies` tap inside the Synaptic package manager when a given package is selected. Usually you don't need to do that if you install things through the repos but since you are building it yourself I guess that's the way to go. :) Hope this helps.

Comment: I was trying to go with the easy way, but I didn't find the PyQt 5.7.1 or greater version when I downloaded with sudo apt-get install. So, I had to compile it from the source. Now I am getting an error
module ` "QtQuick" version 2.7` is not installed and I am able to download `version 1.0` which doesnot fullfill my purpose. Same is with `QtQuckControls 2.0` which I need, but has `version 1.0`

Comment: I would suggest building both the lastest Qt5 with the latest compatible PyQt5 from source. Qt tends to change a lot especially when it comes to QML. There are multiple versions of most QML components and it's a nightmare to deal with all that. That is why I use it only if I'm forced to (for example: project at work). You have `QtQml`, `QtQuick`, `QtQuickControls` and `QtQuickControls2` (you can see all the gory details [here](https://github.com/qt/)) which just shows how much turbulence there currently is when it comes to this part of the Qt framework.