# Run Qt Qml GUI through python 3 in raspberry Pi 3 with pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qml, pyqt5, raspberry-pi3

My problem is exactly the same with the problem from [QtQml installation in Raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036898/qtqml-installation-in-raspberry-pi) but with a little bit more confusion

I want to run a QML based GUI in raspberry PI by running a python code. I designed it with Qt creator in windows. It worked on windows but not on my raspberry pi. This is my code:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QUrl, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView`

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    ctx = engine.rootContext()
    ctx.setContextProperty("main", engine)
    engine.load("main.qml")
    win = engine.rootObjects()[0]
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I want to run it on RasPi, this happened

```
ImportError: No Module Found "PyQt5.QtQml
```

I am using a raspbian but I didn't install qt creator on the raspberry pi because I plan to design the Qt GUI in my pc to save sd card space. I only want the raspi to run the code and the gui.

in the answer here
[QtQml installation in Raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036898/qtqml-installation-in-raspberry-pi) it says that I have to install qtdeclerative5-dev package and the libqt5qml5.

The question is, how do I install those packages? I tried sudo apt-get but it could not locate package. The same goes for pip3.

Please help :( I'm still a newbie in this domain and in this forum

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Something like `sudo apt-get install pip3 qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5qml5`

Comment: @RossRogers I tried sudo apt-get but it could not locate package. The same goes for pip3

Comment: Looks like `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`.  `sudo apt-cache search` for other libs

Comment: maybe a `sudo apt update` first, but I guess You went there - all those years ago :-)